# line breaks when using lemma or proof

Tags: text-manipulation, proof-package, lemma

Sorry for the long MWE but it is only the last part going wrong, but I was unsure if its my preamble making it go wrong, the text in my lemma or proofs runs off the page and I can't see the end of the sentence or my ref.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{parskip} %% <-- added
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

% Standard packages
\usepackage{
float, 
graphicx
}
% Set page margins
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
% Set nice page headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\Tri}[8]{%
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){#1}
\tkzDefPoint({#2,#3}){#4}
\tkzDefPoint({#5,#6}){#7}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=#8](#1,#4,#7)
\tkzLabelPoint[left](#1){$#1$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[below](#4){$#4$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](#7){$#7$}
\tkzDrawPoints(#1,#4,#7)
}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
% Paragraph style}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% Proposition environment
\newenvironment{proposition}
{\begin{center}\em}
{\end{center}}
%Diagram environment
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\stepcounter{CountDiag}\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\par Diagram~\theCountDiag
\end{center}}
%Step environment
\newenvironment{step}
{\stepcounter{CountStep}\vspace*{10pt} Step~\theCountStep\par
{\raggedright}}

\newcounter{CountStep} 
\newcounter{CountDiag}

%Reset counters   
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\setcounter{CountStep}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\setcounter{CountDiag}{0}} 

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Proposition 18}

\begin{proposition} 
In any triangle the angle opposite the greater side is greater.
\end{proposition}

\begin{lemma}
In any triangle $ABC$,if side $\overline{AC}$ greater than $\overline{AB}$,  then     $\angle{ABC}$ is also greater than $\angle{BCA}$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{diagram}
\Tri{B}{-2}{3}{A}{3}{0}{C}{blue,  opacity=0.1}
\end{diagram}

\begin{lemma}
\begin{align*}
&\text{If $\overline{AC}$ is greater than $\overline{AB}$,  then a point $D$ can be     constructed such that $\overline{AD}$ is equal to $\overline{AB}$} &&   I.3,     I.Post.1\\
\end{align*}
\end{lemma}

\begin{diagram}
\Tri{B}{-2}{3}{A}{3}{0}{C}{blue,  opacity=0.1}
%\tkzDrawCircle(A,B)
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(A,B)   \tkzGetPoints{E}{D}
\tkzDrawPoints(D)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](D)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
\end{diagram}
\begin{proof}
\begin{lemma}
\begin{align*}
&\text{In $\triangle{ABC}$, if $\overline{AD}$ is constructed to be equal to     $\overline{AB}$, and $\overline{BD}$ is joined, then the exterior $\angle{ADB}$ is     greater than the interior and opposite $\angle{DCB}$.} &&  I.16\\
&\text{In $\triangle{BCD}$, the exterior angle $\angle{ADB}$ is equal to     $\angle{ABD}$ since $\overline{AD}$ is equal to $\overline{AB}$} && I.5
\end{align*}
\end{lemma}
Therefore in any triangle the angle opposite the greater side is greater.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: " but I was unsure if its my preamble making it go wrong" It is easy for you to test that, you can try removing each of the packages, and if the problem still occurs post the example without that package. Doing that makes it _much_ easier for people to help you.

Comment: you have put all the text in `\text{` which is `\mbox` essentially so forces it all in one line, just remove the `\text` and the `align*` enviornment as this is text not a math alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
\begin{lemma}
\begin{align*}
&\text{If $\overline{AC}$ is greater than $\overline{AB}$,
then a point $D$ can be
     constructed such that $\overline{AD}$ 
is equal to $\overline{AB}$} &&   I.3,     I.Post.1\\
\end{align*}
\end{lemma}
```

the `align*` is doing nothing and the `\text` forces all the text into a single line hbox.

Just use

```
\begin{lemma}
If $\overline{AC}$ is greater than $\overline{AB}$,
then a point $D$ can be
     constructed such that $\overline{AD}$ 
is equal to $\overline{AB}$   I.3,     I.Post.1
\end{lemma}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to align the ref. but now I realised I can just use hfill. Thanks